# How to append a comma to a column except last row in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Consider I have the following table:

```
select * from myTable
```

Which would return the following result

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | FirstValue |
| 2 | SecondValue |
| 3 | ThirdValue |

I need to export the data in a list of JSON objects so I wrote the following script

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(Max)
SET @json = (SELECT * FROM myTable FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('data'))
SELECT '[' UNION ALL

SELECT value+','
FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.data') UNION ALL

SELECT ']'
```

Which returns the below result. I then save the results as a JSON file and use it somewhere else.

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| [ |
| `{"Col1":1,"Col2":"FirstValue"},` |
| `{"Col1":2,"Col2":"SecondValue"},` |
| `{"Col1":3,"Col2":"ThirdValue"},` |
| ] |

This works well but it is a deformed JSON list because of the comma on the last row so I have to do some work after exporting it. Before you suggest **list_agg** or similar functions that concatenate the results in a string value in a single row, note that this is an example. In reality, the tables I need to export have 5M records so I need every value in its own row. I usually just open the file and remove the last comma before the end square bracket but when the files are too big I cannot open them.

So, is there a way to apply the comma on all rows except for the last one in the query directly?

Comment: Add a trim to remove the last character/comma after you build the string.

Comment: the problem here is youre manually building the json - you do know that in sql server 2016 and on there is built in json functions that work pretty fantastically? They might not be the most performant in some scenarios but they do work - i use them quite often. FOR JSON_AUTO is something you should go and read up on in the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear why you would want to have the JSON data on separate rows, but you can use this code instead:

```sql
SELECT Json
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS Ordering, '[' AS Json
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
     2,
     (SELECT Col1, Col2
      FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)
     + CASE WHEN LEAD(Col1) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) IS NULL THEN N'' ELSE N',' END
    FROM myTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, ']' Json
) ORDER BY Ordering
```

The steps are as follows:

- Construct a union of the `[]` brackets and the JSON
- The JSON is constructed using a correlated subquery, returning a single JSON object per row.
- Add a comma if the next row is not null
- Sort by the `ordering` column to get it in the right order

Comment: To answer your question, if I try to concatenate 5M rows of data in a cell I reach MAX CHAR and the end of the cell is truncated. Thanks for the code. This is how I integrated it.
`
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(Max)
SET @json = (SELECT * FROM myTable FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('data'))
SELECT '[' UNION ALL

SELECT value + CASE WHEN LEAD(value) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ',' END FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.data') UNION ALL

SELECT ']';
`

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by "MAX CHAR" and "cell", because `FOR JSON` outputs `nvarchar(max)` which can be up to 2GB. The idea behind my code was to forgo the local variable in the first place

Comment: Yes, my results are over 4GB at times

Comment: I note that if your data is so large, you won't be able to store it in a local variable anyway, this solution on the other hand just streams out the result without buffering it anywhere